# Count Repeated occurence of a substring in string

Tags: python, regex, string, count

Suppose I have a string like this

```
aa = 'booked#booked#available#available#available#available#available#booked#available#booked'
```

Now I want to find out that `'available'` substring has occur in this string how many times repeatedly. So in this case it should be 5 as `'available' is coming 5 times repeatedly,it will be much helpful if someone can give a python library function itself to get this, regex solutions are also welcoming.

what I have tried so far is

```
aa.count('#available')
```

which is obviously giving me 6,

```
aa.count('#available#available')
```

which is again wrong.

```
import re
count(re.findall('available#'))
```

is also wrong

Comment: just to clarify, you want to only count the repetitions? so all instances except the first one?

Comment: OP wants to count contiguous occurrences.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from itertools is splendid for these types of problems:

```
from itertools import groupby
aa = 'booked#booked#available#available#available#available#available#booked#available#booked'
words = aa.split('#')
for key, group in groupby(words):
    print len(list(group)), key
```

Output:

```
2 booked
5 available
1 booked
1 available
1 booked
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it in 2.7.

```
import re
aa = 'booked#booked#available#available#available#available#available#booked#available#booked'
len(re.findall('#available', aa))
```

I think you can safely remove the pound sign based on the pattern you provided.

```
>>> stuff = re.findall('available', aa)
>>> stuff
['available', 'available', 'available', 'available', 'available', 'available']
```